# How do I create a List of Class objects, all of which implement a particular interface?

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have a set of classes as follows:

there is an interface Interface1, and there are two classes Class1 and Class2, both which implement Interface1.

`interface Interface1 {
}`

`class Class1 implements Interface1{
}`

`class Class2 implements Interface1{}`

Now, I want to create a List of classes that implement Interface1. I was trying to do something like:

`List<Class<Interface1>> classes = new List<Class<Interface1>>();`
`classes.add(Class1.class);`
`classes.add(Class2.class);`

But this doesn't work. I get the compiler error: 
`Class1.class is of type Class<Class1> and so cannot be added to the list`

Is there a way to achieve what I intend to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a wildcard bounded by your `interface` type

```
List<Class<? extends Interface1>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Interface1>>();
classes.add(Class1.class);
classes.add(Class2.class);
classes.add(String.class); // won't compile
```